# Integral of ratio of polynomial

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

**Question**:
I am trying to solve the following integral:
$$\int\limits_{-x_0}^{x_0} \frac{|x|^{\alpha}}{x-c}\; dx$$

with $c\in \mathbb{C}$, $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^+$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Attempts**: 
I split the absolute value and work on
 $$\int\limits_{0}^{x_0} \frac{x^{\alpha}}{x-c}\; dx,$$
I substitute $x'=x+c$ and then apply [Newton's generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem). 
$$\int\limits_{0}^{x_0}\frac{x^{\alpha}}{x-c}\; dx=\int\limits_{-c}^{x_0-c} \frac{\left(x+c\right)^{\alpha}}{x}dx \;=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{k}\int\limits_{-c}^{x_0-c}dx\;\left\{\begin{array}{r}x^{\alpha-k-1}c^k,&|x|>|c|\\
x^{k-1}c^{\alpha-k},&|x|<|c|\end{array} \right. .$$
Then I can integrate over $x$.

This looks rather complicated though, as I have to consider different cases depending on the relative size of the absolute value of $x$ and $c$ to apply the binomial theorem correctly, thus breaking the integral and so on.

Any suggestion to solve this in a better way?

Comment: $x^\alpha$ is not defined for $x <0$. And the sum isn’t up to $\alpha$ if you use Newton’s generalized binomial theorem. Please check further your question.

Comment: Sorry about the errors, I wrote it by heart without checking. Indeed, I have to integrate the absolute value, so I split it and integrate only from 0 to $x_0$. Fixed.

Comment: what is $C{}{}$ ?

Comment: Complex numbers, I didn;t know how to typeset it the right way and hoped it was clear

Comment: Use \mathbb{C}  and, \mathbb{R} to get $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$.